# filter for povray

Tags: context

Is it possible to put directly povray files in ConTeXt document using filter module ? I try with this example, but I  get white page. Maybe it's more complicated ? (I use linux)

```tex
\setuppapersize[A4][A4]
\setupcolors[state=start]

\usemodule[filter]
\defineexternalfilter
  [povray]
  [
directory=povtemp/, 
output={\externalfilterbasefile.png},
    filtercommand={povray "\externalfilterbasefile"  "povtemp/\externalfilterbasefile" "\externalfilterinputfile"},
  
  ]
  
  
  \starttext 

My first povray render file :
  
  \startbuffer[test.pov]
  // PoVRay 3.7 Scene File " ... .pov"
// author:  ...
// date:    ...
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
#version 3.7;
global_settings{ assumed_gamma 1.0 }
#default{ finish{ ambient 0.1 diffuse 0.9 }} 
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include "colors.inc"
#include "textures.inc"
#include "glass.inc"
#include "metals.inc"
#include "golds.inc"
#include "stones.inc"
#include "woods.inc"
#include "shapes.inc"
#include "shapes2.inc"
#include "functions.inc"
#include "math.inc"
#include "transforms.inc"
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
// camera ------------------------------------------------------------------
#declare Camera_0 = camera {/*ultra_wide_angle*/ angle 75      // front view
                            location  <-3.0 , 1.0 ,-3.0>
                            right     x*image_width/image_height
                            look_at   <0.0 , 1.0 , 0.0>}
#declare Camera_1 = camera {/*ultra_wide_angle*/ angle 90   // diagonal view
                            location  <2.0 , 2.5 ,-3.0>
                            right     x*image_width/image_height
                            look_at   <0.0 , 1.0 , 0.0>}
#declare Camera_2 = camera {/*ultra_wide_angle*/ angle 90  //right side view
                            location  <-3 , 1 , 0.0>
                            right     x*image_width/image_height
                            look_at   <0.0 , 1.0 , 0.0>}
#declare Camera_3 = camera {/*ultra_wide_angle*/ angle 90        // top view
                            location  <0.0 , 4.0 ,-1>
                            right     x*image_width/image_height
                            look_at   <0.0 , 1.0 , 0.0>}
camera{Camera_0}
// sun ---------------------------------------------------------------------
light_source{< -3000, 3000, -3000> color White}
// sky ---------------------------------------------------------------------
sky_sphere { pigment { color rgb <1.0,1.0,1.0>} 
          
           } //end of skysphere
      
              
              
    // = = = = = = = = = = == 
              
              #declare White_Marble_Map =
color_map {
    [0.0 rgb <0.9, 0.9, 0.9>]
    [0.8 rgb <0.5, 0.5, 0.5>]
    [1.0 rgb <0.2, 0.2, 0.2>]
}      
  
  //------------------------------------- 
   
     box {
    
     <-1,0,-1>,<1,0,1>
              texture { pigment{ color rgb<23,128,237>/255 filter .66 } // < 0.0, 0.5, 1.0> greenish blue  
                // normal { bumps 0.5 scale 0.05 }
                   finish { phong 1}
                 } // end of texture 

    
    } 
    
//-------------------------------------------------------
      
  sphere { <0,0,0>, 0.5 
                          texture{pigment{color Yellow filter .66 }finish{phong .8}}
             
              

          scale<1,1,1>  rotate<0,0,0>  translate<0,0.5,0>  
       }  // end of sphere ----------------------------------- 
       

  \stopbuffer
  
  

  
  \stoptext
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more of an extended comment .... The solution posted by Marjin can be improved a little. First, you can use `cache=yes` to ensure that the successive files get a different number. I have also collected the common options in a buffer and then included that using the `bufferbefore` option:

```
\usemodule[filter]
\define[1]\readPNGfile{\externalfigure[#1]}

\defineexternalfilter
  [povray]
  [
    filtercommand={povray +O\externalfilteroutputfile\space +I\externalfilterinputfile},
    output={\externalfilterbasefile.png},
    readcommand=\readPNGfile,
    cache=yes,
    bufferbefore=pov-header,
  ]


\startbuffer[pov-header]
  // PoVRay 3.7 Scene File " ... .pov"
  // author:  ...
  // date:    ...
  //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  #version 3.7;
  global_settings{ assumed_gamma 1.0 }
  #default{ finish{ ambient 0.1 diffuse 0.9 }} 
  //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  #include "colors.inc"
  #include "textures.inc"
  #include "glass.inc"
  #include "metals.inc"
  #include "golds.inc"
  #include "stones.inc"
  #include "woods.inc"
  #include "shapes.inc"
  #include "shapes2.inc"
  #include "functions.inc"
  #include "math.inc"
  #include "transforms.inc"

  //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  // camera ------------------------------------------------------------------

  #declare Camera_0 = camera {/*ultra_wide_angle*/ angle 75      // front view
           location  <-3.0 , 1.0 ,-3.0>
           right     x*image_width/image_height
           look_at   <0.0 , 1.0 , 0.0>}

  #declare Camera_1 = camera {/*ultra_wide_angle*/ angle 90   // diagonal view
           location  <2.0 , 2.5 ,-3.0>
           right     x*image_width/image_height
           look_at   <0.0 , 1.0 , 0.0>}

  #declare Camera_2 = camera {/*ultra_wide_angle*/ angle 90  //right side view
           location  <-3 , 1 , 0.0>
           right     x*image_width/image_height
           look_at   <0.0 , 1.0 , 0.0>}
  #declare Camera_3 = camera {/*ultra_wide_angle*/ angle 90        // top view
           location  <0.0 , 4.0 ,-1>
           right     x*image_width/image_height
           look_at   <0.0 , 1.0 , 0.0>}
\stopbuffer

\starttext 

My first povray render file :

\startpovray
  camera{Camera_0}

  // sun 
  light_source{< -3000, 3000, -3000> color White}

  // sky
  sky_sphere { pigment {color rgb <1.0,1.0,1.0>} }

  #declare White_Marble_Map = color_map {
           [0.0 rgb <0.9, 0.9, 0.9>]
           [0.8 rgb <0.5, 0.5, 0.5>]
           [1.0 rgb <0.2, 0.2, 0.2>]
           }      

  box { <-1,0,-1>,<1,0,1>
        texture { pigment{ color rgb<23,128,237>/255 filter .66 }
                  finish { phong 1}
                }
      } 

  sphere { <0,0,0>, 0.5 
           texture{ pigment{ color Yellow filter .66 }
                    finish { phong .8 }
                  }
           scale<1,1,1>  rotate<0,0,0>  translate<0,0.5,0>  
  } 
\stoppovray  

and another one

\startpovray
  camera{Camera_0}

  // sun 
  light_source{< -3000, 3000, -3000> color White}

  // sky
  sky_sphere { pigment {color rgb <1.0,1.0,1.0>} }

  #declare White_Marble_Map = color_map {
           [0.0 rgb <0.9, 0.9, 0.9>]
           [0.8 rgb <0.5, 0.5, 0.5>]
           [1.0 rgb <0.2, 0.2, 0.2>]
           }      

  box { <-1,0,-1>,<1,0,1>
        texture { pigment{ color rgb<23,128,237>/255 filter .66 }
                  finish { phong 1}
                }
      } 

  sphere { <0,0,0>, 0.5 
           texture { pigment{color Red filter .66 }
                     finish{phong .8}
                   }
           scale<1,1,1>  rotate<0,0,0>  translate<0,0.5,0>  
         } 
\stoppovray  
\stoptext
```

Comment: thank you, I see your answer  now.

Answer (score 2):

The basic `povray` syntax is `povray +Ooutputfile.png inputfile.pov`. If the input file does not have the `.pov` extension (but for example `.tmp`) then the command should be `povray +Ooutputfile.png +Iinputfile.tmp`, so `+I` must be prepended to the filename. Furthermore the space between the two options is removed by LaTeX, so you need to add an explicit `\space` there.

The `filter` module for ConTeXt can be used in various ways, below I have used the variant using `\start[filtername]` and `\stop[filtername]` as described on https://github.com/adityam/filter, so in this case `\startpovray` and `\endpovray`.

One important issue is that a filter by default includes the output from the filter into the document directly, i.e., it expects ConTeXt syntax as output, or at least plain text. For `povray` in this case the output is a `.png` file, so you need to set the `readcommand` in the filter explicitly to include a graphics file.

Edit: if you want to include multiple `povray` outputs then you need to change the output filename between runs, otherwise a new run overwrites the PNG file from the previous run. This can be done with an optional argument for `\startpovray` that is incorporated into the `output` setting using the `\externalfilterparameter` command. The first code block does not need this optional argument, which may be convenient if you want to include just a single image. The second block in the example below now uses `\startpovray[id=second]` to set the optional parameter to the value `second` which will be used in the filename for this block.

MWE:

```
\setuppapersize[A4][A4]
\setupcolors[state=start]

\usemodule[filter]
\def\readPNGfile#1{\externalfigure[#1]}
\defineexternalfilter
  [povray]
  [filtercommand={povray +O\externalfilteroutputfile\space +I\externalfilterinputfile},
  id=default,
  output={\externalfilterparameter{id}.png},
  readcommand=\readPNGfile,
  ]
  
\starttext 

My first povray render file :

\startpovray
// PoVRay 3.7 Scene File " ... .pov"
// author:  ...
// date:    ...
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
#version 3.7;
global_settings{ assumed_gamma 1.0 }
#default{ finish{ ambient 0.1 diffuse 0.9 }} 
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include "colors.inc"
#include "textures.inc"
#include "glass.inc"
#include "metals.inc"
#include "golds.inc"
#include "stones.inc"
#include "woods.inc"
#include "shapes.inc"
#include "shapes2.inc"
#include "functions.inc"
#include "math.inc"
#include "transforms.inc"
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
// camera ------------------------------------------------------------------
#declare Camera_0 = camera {/*ultra_wide_angle*/ angle 75      // front view
                            location  <-3.0 , 1.0 ,-3.0>
                            right     x*image_width/image_height
                            look_at   <0.0 , 1.0 , 0.0>}
#declare Camera_1 = camera {/*ultra_wide_angle*/ angle 90   // diagonal view
                            location  <2.0 , 2.5 ,-3.0>
                            right     x*image_width/image_height
                            look_at   <0.0 , 1.0 , 0.0>}
#declare Camera_2 = camera {/*ultra_wide_angle*/ angle 90  //right side view
                            location  <-3 , 1 , 0.0>
                            right     x*image_width/image_height
                            look_at   <0.0 , 1.0 , 0.0>}
#declare Camera_3 = camera {/*ultra_wide_angle*/ angle 90        // top view
                            location  <0.0 , 4.0 ,-1>
                            right     x*image_width/image_height
                            look_at   <0.0 , 1.0 , 0.0>}
camera{Camera_0}
// sun ---------------------------------------------------------------------
light_source{< -3000, 3000, -3000> color White}
// sky ---------------------------------------------------------------------
sky_sphere { pigment { color rgb <1.0,1.0,1.0>} 
          
           } //end of skysphere
      
              
              
    // = = = = = = = = = = == 
              
              #declare White_Marble_Map =
color_map {
    [0.0 rgb <0.9, 0.9, 0.9>]
    [0.8 rgb <0.5, 0.5, 0.5>]
    [1.0 rgb <0.2, 0.2, 0.2>]
}      
  
  //------------------------------------- 
   
     box {
    
     <-1,0,-1>,<1,0,1>
              texture { pigment{ color rgb<23,128,237>/255 filter .66 } // < 0.0, 0.5, 1.0> greenish blue  
                // normal { bumps 0.5 scale 0.05 }
                   finish { phong 1}
                 } // end of texture 

    
    } 
    
//-------------------------------------------------------
      
  sphere { <0,0,0>, 0.5 
                          texture{pigment{color Yellow filter .66 }finish{phong .8}}
             
              

          scale<1,1,1>  rotate<0,0,0>  translate<0,0.5,0>  
       }  // end of sphere ----------------------------------- 
  \stoppovray  

and another one

  \startpovray[id=second]
  // PoVRay 3.7 Scene File " ... .pov"
// author:  ...
// date:    ...
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
#version 3.7;
global_settings{ assumed_gamma 1.0 }
#default{ finish{ ambient 0.1 diffuse 0.9 }} 
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include "colors.inc"
#include "textures.inc"
#include "glass.inc"
#include "metals.inc"
#include "golds.inc"
#include "stones.inc"
#include "woods.inc"
#include "shapes.inc"
#include "shapes2.inc"
#include "functions.inc"
#include "math.inc"
#include "transforms.inc"
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
// camera ------------------------------------------------------------------
#declare Camera_0 = camera {/*ultra_wide_angle*/ angle 75      // front view
                            location  <-3.0 , 1.0 ,-3.0>
                            right     x*image_width/image_height
                            look_at   <0.0 , 1.0 , 0.0>}
#declare Camera_1 = camera {/*ultra_wide_angle*/ angle 90   // diagonal view
                            location  <2.0 , 2.5 ,-3.0>
                            right     x*image_width/image_height
                            look_at   <0.0 , 1.0 , 0.0>}
#declare Camera_2 = camera {/*ultra_wide_angle*/ angle 90  //right side view
                            location  <-3 , 1 , 0.0>
                            right     x*image_width/image_height
                            look_at   <0.0 , 1.0 , 0.0>}
#declare Camera_3 = camera {/*ultra_wide_angle*/ angle 90        // top view
                            location  <0.0 , 4.0 ,-1>
                            right     x*image_width/image_height
                            look_at   <0.0 , 1.0 , 0.0>}
camera{Camera_0}
// sun ---------------------------------------------------------------------
light_source{< -3000, 3000, -3000> color White}
// sky ---------------------------------------------------------------------
sky_sphere { pigment { color rgb <1.0,1.0,1.0>} 
          
           } //end of skysphere
      
              
              
    // = = = = = = = = = = == 
              
              #declare White_Marble_Map =
color_map {
    [0.0 rgb <0.9, 0.9, 0.9>]
    [0.8 rgb <0.5, 0.5, 0.5>]
    [1.0 rgb <0.2, 0.2, 0.2>]
}      
  
  //------------------------------------- 
   
     box {
    
     <-1,0,-1>,<1,0,1>
              texture { pigment{ color rgb<23,128,237>/255 filter .66 } // < 0.0, 0.5, 1.0> greenish blue  
                // normal { bumps 0.5 scale 0.05 }
                   finish { phong 1}
                 } // end of texture 

    
    } 
    
//-------------------------------------------------------
      
  sphere { <0,0,0>, 0.5 
                          texture{pigment{color Red filter .66 }finish{phong .8}}
             
              

          scale<1,1,1>  rotate<0,0,0>  translate<0,0.5,0>  
       }  // end of sphere ----------------------------------- 
  \stoppovray  
\stoptext
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you !  Now it works like a charm.

Comment: Last question: How to reduce white spaces between text and image ? I put size=crop. Nothing happened.

Comment: @Aviroum The whitespace in the example is present in the (png) image itself, so the best way would be to write the povray code in such a way that a larger part of the image is occupied by the objects. In ConTeXt you could manually cut off a bit of the image at the top, but that would be difficult to incorporate in the filter, and that would also go against the idea of the filter in the first place (i.e., provide automatic compilation and inclusion of the povray code). If you need to post-process individual images then it would make more sense to just compile them in the terminal.

Comment: For  more pov files in the same document, this solution is still valid. I get trouble when I put a second pov code. I compare with Lilypond multipages ([wiki][https://wiki.contextgarden.net/LilyPond]) ?

Comment: @Aviroum see edit for support for multiple images.

Comment: Oh ! Perfect. That's what I want. Thank you.

Comment: For multiple code snippets, it is better to use `cache=yes`, which will automatically include a counter in the file name (and cache the images so that povray is run only when the file has changed.

Comment: @Aditya that didn't work in this case, the input filename is different with `cache=yes` but the output filename is the same (at least with `output={\externalfilterbasefile.png}` set, which is needed to catch the `povray` result properly). Therefore the png file is overwritten and the final result is used for all snippets.

Comment: OK. I'll try to create a complete example.

Comment: @Aditya your example works nicely (I didn't expect otherwise, since you wrote the module...). When I tried it before I didn't put a comma after `cache=yes` (because it was the last option), that together with the closing `]` on the next line (instead of directly after the option) caused a problem with caching.